npm:cli.js does not exist
$ which npm
/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.3/bin/npm

~/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.3/bin$ cat npm
#!/usr/bin/env node
require('../lib/cli.js')(process)

However, when I navigate to ~/.nvm/versions/node/v21.7.3/lib, which should contain the ../lib directory, I only find the node_modules directory and no cli.js file.
npm and node are working correctly. What I am trying to understand is why the npm command is running correctly when the above is the case.
The npm cli source code is correctly stored in the node_modules directory
